# Create instance gateway on AWS with Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I'm trying to create a gateway on an aws ec2 amazon linux machine so that a worker machine without access to the internet can gain access via the gateway. The way I would usually do it on debian and a local virtual environment would be:

on gateway machine:

- enable ipv4 forwarding
- add iptable rule for postrouting masquerading
- restart network

on worker machine:

- add default gateway to /etc/network/interfaces
- restart network

And that's it. On the amazon linux machine, being a redhat based distro, I do it the following way:

- enable ipv4 forwarding
- `add iptable rule for postrouting masquerading`
- restart network

on worker machine:

- `ip route add default via GATEWAY_MACHINE_IP`

And then it's just hangs because I lost my ssh connection. I also tried modifying the interface file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ and I lose the ssh connection when restarting the network.

The gateway machine is in a security group that allows all ipv4 incoming connections from all sources and ssh from my local computer, and allows all outgoing traffic to any destination.

The worker machine is in a different security group that allows all traffic from and to the gateway machine and ssh from my local computer.

Something I've noticed is that AWS only uses one interface for public and private connections, so maybe that has something to do with what's going on?

I was hoping somebody give me some insight as to what I'm doing wrong and if it's even possible to do what I'm trying to do in AWS

Comment: When you say "so that a worker machine without access to the internet", are you saying that the 'worker' in a **private subnet**? In the AWS world, it is typically an EC2 instance in a **private subnet** that routes its traffic via a NAT Instance in a **public subnet**. Aside from configuring the NAT Instance, it requires a change to the Route Table of the private subnet to route traffic to the NAT Instance, plus deactivating the source/dest check on the NAT Instance.

Comment: Actually, they're both on the default VPC's default subnet. I'll look into putting them in different subnets.

Comment: Of course, another way to prevent an instance from reaching the Internet is simply not to give it a Public IP address.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing :D Thanks a ton for the help. I was able to make it work and I think I understand AWS a little better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Elastic network interfaces - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html):

> You must **disable source/destination checks** if the instance runs services such as network address translation, routing, or firewalls.

By default, the VPC will only allow traffic into an instance if the destination IP address 'belongs' to the instance. However, since you are performing NAT on the instance, it will be receiving packets with a different destination IP address.

Therefore:

- Select the NAT instance in the EC2 console
- Go to **Actions** / **Networking**
- Select **Change Source/Destination Check**

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. It still loses the ssh connection after I enter the "ip route add default via GATEWAY_INSTANCE_IP" and I'm unable to connect after that. I have all incoming and outward traffic enabled between the gateway instance and the worker instance.

Comment: You would certainly lose any current SSH connection, since the path your traffic takes would be cut-off. Plus, you shouldn't be able to SSH into it again because traffic would be routed to the Gateway Instance, so any response to your SSH request wouldn't get to you.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. I'll look into solving that part of the problem. Thanks for the help!